# Spring Configuration bean not eligible for getting processed by BeanPostProcessors

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

I am building a multi module Spring Boot project, which will implement Spring’s SOAP Web Services.
One of the classes is as follows:

```
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MyWebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter{
   …
}
```

The following message is  logged immediately after application startup

```
Bean “myWebServiceConfig of type [com.mycompany.MyWebServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c32dec5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

(For simplicity, am not including the beans within the configuration class which are required as part of Spring's SOAP endpoint configuration. Nor am I including the `@EnableWS` annotation. The same message is logged with or without these).

If there is no auto proxying, nothing is going to work.

I have tried annotating the class with `@Lazy` and `Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)`, but these do not help.

While I have seen others with the same issue resolve it using `DependsOn`, I do not know how that would work here.

Apart from those provided by Spring, there are no classes I am aware of within the application which implement `BeanPostProcessor`.

Furthermore, if `MyWebServiceConfig` is deleted, the same message is displayed about the following class:

```
com.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWebServiceConfiguration
```

which lives in `spring-ws-core-3.1.3.jar`
and I obviously have no control over.
This jar is a transient dependency of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Debugging, this message which appears on startup is logged in the following class:

```
PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.
```

This has an inner class, `BeanPostProcessorChecker`
which includes the following method:

```
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
    f (! (bean instanceof BeanPostProcessor) &&!this.isInfrastructureBean (beanName) G& this. beanFactory.getBeanPostProcessorCount() <    this.beanPostProcessorTargetCount && Logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
   … log message
```

Can anyone assist

Thanks

Comment: And why do you think this is an issue?

Comment: will update after testing the SOAP WS, thanks